# nulls on pg_stat_get_progress_info('VACUUM') columns on pg_exporter role

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, vacuum, postgresql-12, autovacuum

I'm trying to export the results of a query `select * from pg_stat_progress_vacuum;`. The problem is that the only column values I can see from the created user are:

- pid
- datid
- datname

Other columns are constantly null. When query is run from superuser account there are values of course.

Based on `pg_stat_progress_vacuum` view definition I noticed that the problematic part is usage of `pg_stat_get_progress_info` function with `VACUUM` parameter (view names params returned by this function).

User has `pg_monitor` role assigned.

What am I missing?

Result of `select * from pg_stat_progress_vacuum;` from monitoring user

```
[
  {
    "pid": 33079,
    "datid": 16410,
    "datname": "<database name>",
    "relid": null,
    "phase": null,
    "heap_blks_total": null,
    "heap_blks_scanned": null,
    "heap_blks_vacuumed": null,
    "index_vacuum_count": null,
    "max_dead_tuples": null,
    "num_dead_tuples": null
  },
  {
    "pid": 38625,
    "datid": 121786502,
    "datname": "<database name>",
    "relid": null,
    "phase": null,
    "heap_blks_total": null,
    "heap_blks_scanned": null,
    "heap_blks_vacuumed": null,
    "index_vacuum_count": null,
    "max_dead_tuples": null,
    "num_dead_tuples": null
  }
]
```

Result from superuser for the same query

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_progress_vacuum;
  pid  |   datid   |     datname      |   relid   |       phase       | heap_blks_total | heap_blks_scanned | heap_blks_vacuumed | index_vacuum_count | max_dead_tuples | num_dead_tuples
-------+-----------+------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------
 38625 | 121786502 | <database name> | 121786624 | vacuuming indexes |         7091104 |           7091104 |                  0 |                  0 |       178956970 |        73659774
(1 row)
```

A couple of seconds passed from one query execution to the other, so I assume that just autovacuum has finished thus the difference in row count.

Postgres version is 12.2

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the required privileges.

To see all values in a line of `pg_stat_progress_vacuum`, one of the following must be satisfied:

- you are a superuser
- the `VACUUM` is run by the same user as your current connection
- you are a member of the system role `pg_read_all_stats`

Comment: User that I'm using has `pg_monitor` role assigned which according to the documentation should also include `pg_read_all_stats` role. I forgot to mention that - I've edited the post to include this information.

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong, because a user that is a member of `pg_monitor` can definitely see the data. I just verified it. Does `\du` confirm that? Perhaps you are connected as a different user.

Comment: Yup, `\du` shows that this user has `pg_monitor` role assigned.

Comment: The only way I can think of to resolve this is if you add a complete SQL script to the question that shows what you observer so that the behavior can be reproduced...

Comment: I've added queries results to the question.

Comment: No, a complete reproducible test case that I can run, including `CREATE ROLE` and GRANT` and everything, so that I can see that happen on my machine. Otherwise I won't believe it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same issue on Postgres 11.3 and finish up with the following solution:

1. Define wrapper function from superuser:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_stat_progress_vacuum()
 RETURNS SETOF pg_stat_progress_vacuum
 LANGUAGE sql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$ 
select * from pg_stat_progress_vacuum;
$function$;
```

2. Use it from monitoring user as:

```sql
select * from my_stat_progress_vacuum();
```

3. Same trick would be useful to access other views from pg_stat_* family